# for loop to skip few steps

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to find a way to skip steps inbetween(150 till 200) when the ${x} == 4 during the step 100. What is the best possible way. I tried to set step=250 but it was changed back to 150.

```
for step in $(seq "$stepnum" 50 650)
do
        case $step in
        "50")
             # do something
         ;;
        "100")

# do something
             if [[ ${x} == 4 ]]
           then
               step=250
            fi
               ## skip to step 250
         ;;
        "150")
# do something
         ;;
        "200")
# do something
         ;;
        "250")
        ;;
    *)

    ;;
    esac
```

Comment: Could this maybe be an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? This construction looks rather weird to begin with. What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Use an arithmetic `for` expression instead of `in`:

```
for (( step=stepnum ; step+=50 ; step<=650 ))
```

This is the difference:

- Using `in`, the loop variable will iterate through each member of the list provided by `seq` in your example, no matter how you modify the counter.
- Using the arithmetic `for`, the loop variable will be incremented as indicated in the second statement of the loop head, so it will work as intended if you modify the counter in the loop body.

Type `help for` or `man bash` to learn more about the `for` syntax.

Comment: We don't want to change the for loop syntax as it been used everywhere. I just want to change inside the case block only.

Comment: @user1595858: I understand. You definitely can't modify the loop variable from within the loop body using the `for..in` syntax, but I've added another solution. It's ugly, but it's inside the `case`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing this solution because the OP has indicated that they do not want to modify the loop syntax. The resulting code is not well structured:

```
if [[ ${x} == 4 ]] && [ step -gt 100 ] && [ step -lt 250 ]
then
  continue
fi
```

Add this snippet before the `case`.

Answer (score 0):

A `continue` placed at the beginning of the loop is one approach that will do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

stepnum=50
x=${1:-0}     # x is 0 by default, set with 1st argument on command line

for step in $(seq "$stepnum" 50 650)
do
        [ $step -ge 150 -a $step -le 200 -a $x -eq 4 ] && continue

        case $step in
        "50")
            # do something
            printf "   50 hit\n"
        ;;
        "100")
            # do something
            printf "  100 hit\n"
        ;;
        "150")
            # do something
            printf "  150 hit\n"
        ;;
        "200")
            # do something
            printf "  200 hit\n"
        ;;
        "250")
            # do something
            printf "  250 hit\n"
        ;;
        *)
            # do something
            printf "  %3d - default hit\n" $step
        ;;
        esac
done

exit 0
```

**output (x=4)**

```
$ bash caseseq.sh 4
   50 hit
  100 hit
  250 hit
  300 - default hit
  350 - default hit
  400 - default hit
  450 - default hit
  500 - default hit
  550 - default hit
  600 - default hit
  650 - default hit
```

**output (x=anything else)**

```
$ bash caseseq.sh
   50 hit
  100 hit
  150 hit
  200 hit
  250 hit
  300 - default hit
  350 - default hit
  400 - default hit
  450 - default hit
  500 - default hit
  550 - default hit
  600 - default hit
  650 - default hit
```

**note:** to just skip `150`:

```
        [ $step -eq 150 ] && continue
```

**Example: Change `for` Loop Index**

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i< 10; i++)); do

    [[ $i == [257] ]] && ((i++))
    printf "index %s\n" $i

done
```

**Output**

```
$ bash chgidx.sh
index 0
index 1
index 3
index 4
index 6
index 8
index 9
```

Comment: @david-c-rankin: Your solution does something different than the OP's script would do (assuming the loop variable was modifiable from inside which it is not due to the `for..in` syntax). Specifically you are skipping starting with 150 instead of 100, and you are skipping unconditionally instead of only when the test `$x == 4` is true.

Comment: True, I misunderstood the `$x == 4` requirement. Don't be mislead, the index **can** be changed in a `for..in` loop, but it **cannot** be changed when the index is `seq first inc las`. It is `seq` that prevent reindexing. Just add the `x -eq 4` test. (I'll edit)

Comment: Could you provide an example where you change the index inside a `for..in` loop's body?

Comment: See the **Example: Change `for` Loop Index** added above.

Comment: I hate to be nitpicking, but that is not `for..in` syntax (there is no `in`). That is arithmetic `for` syntax, which allows modification of the variable, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: No, I see your point. that is not a `for .. in` loop, and when I explained earlier that you couldn't reindex due to `seq` what I meant was you cannot change whatever you are using for the `list` in that context. So the better answer is you can't reindex a `for .. in .. some list` loop, but you can reindex a `c-style for` loop. Good catch.